# limited number of items in the plot browser option in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

When dealing with figures including several plots, sometimes you want to select a number of plots. The way I usually do it is opening the `plot browser` in the `view` section and it mostly is good enough. As you can see in the following snapshot, the plot browser does not show more than a specific number of plots, and is saying `and 89 more ...`

[image]

How can I access the other 89 plots? Is there any setting that you can force `MATLAB` to show all the plots in the `plot browser`?

Answer (score 0):

In the command line, you can use

`plotList = findobj(get(gca,'Children'),'Type','Line')`

This will give you a list of handles to all of your plots. You can perform actions on any of these plots. For example - changing the color of the second and fourth plots to red:

`set(plotList([2,4]),'Color','r')`

Removing the third and sixth plots:

`delete(plotList([3,6]))`